# Realistic Bounce (Using Trig?)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

**background:** I am making a graphics program where the major purpose of it is to have a ball (traveling on an arbitrary slope) to bounce realistically off of a line (which is also at a arbitrary slope). By realistically, I mean that I want the ball to bounce off of the line at the same angle it hit, *relative to the line*. The whole program is coordinate based.

**what I've figured out so far:** I've derived a formula for rotating on point around another to an arbitrary degree (using trig). Also, I've figured out how to find the angle that the two "lines" make when they intersect.

**problem:** I can't figure out how to put all of the pieces together and complete the problem.

---

Thanks for any help and tell me if there is any clarification needed!

Comment: Probably more suited for something like stackoverflow.com. Given the current vector of velocity of the ball, when it hits the line, you want the vector reflected through the line.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: you would need to adjust the bounce-off angle to take into account the coefficient of restitution of the particla and surface. The angles as you descibe would only be equal if the collision is perfectly elastic.

Comment: @DavidQuinn "By realistically, I mean that I want the ball to bounce off of the line at the same angle it hit, relative to the line." He's not talking about anything other than the usual simple bounce.